# django, set csrf token on form in static pages

Tags: android, django, cordova, django-views, csrf

I'm a little confused. 
The csrf token is set in the django templates

With the tag:

```
{{csrf_token}}
```

However, my app is a Cordova app, which means that there's nothing loading from the server.
The pages are fetched from the device's memory.

How do I get the csrf_token in that case?

I thought of making a view, which I will call with ajax, that will simply return the csrf_token string to the caller.

Is that how you do it? Will that break the csrf_token security?
Maybe there are better solutions?

If that solution is the correct one, please tell how do you get the csrf token from the request.

So just to reiterate the problem in a little different way: I need to submit a form from a static page.However, when I do so, I get csrf errors.

How do I submit the form without getting csrf errors?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sligodave was linking to the correct docs but instead of the exact process that is described in Django you need to just do an extra step or getting the csrf. If you use [ensure_csrf_token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) to create a view for yourself that you can just fetch the cookie from, you can use JS to fetch and parse that cookie, then turn around and use it on your POST. Since the request(s) are on the same domain there should not be any issues with passing it. I will defer to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20242/ajax-and-csrf-protection) over at security stack to say there is no innate security flaw in this practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want can be achieved using a little bit of javascript.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

You get the csrf token from the cookie and set it as a header on your response or alternatively, you set the csrf field on your form.

EDIT: Never mind, I missed the "static" part of your question. It never goes through django so there's no csrf cookie. I'll get my coat!